# jboss fatal starting deployment

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

Trying to start JBoss EAP 6.2.3.GA I get the errors:

> 14:31:43,523 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) JBAS015005: Reliable deployment behaviour is not possible when auto-deployment of exploded content is enabled (i.e. deployment without use of ".dodeploy"' marker files). Configuration of auto-deployment of exploded content is not recommended in any situation where reliability is desired. Configuring the deployment scanner's auto-deploy-exploded setting to "false" is recommended.
>
> 14:31:44,977 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 18) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myear.ear")]) - failure description: "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [(\"deployment\" => \"myear.ear\")]"
>
> 14:31:44,977 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) "JBAS014784: Failed executing subsystem deployment-scanner boot operations"
>
> 14:31:44,977 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015000: Cannot delete deployment progress marker file U:\JBOSS_CFG\deployments\myear.ear.isdeploying
>
> 14:31:45,025 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
>
> 14:31:45,042 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.2.3.GA (AS 7.3.3.Final-redhat-3) stopped in 10ms
>
> 14:31:45,042 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015000: Cannot delete deployment progress marker file U:\JBOSS_CFG\deployments\mywar.war.isdeploying

Comment: Looks like you have a duplicate EAR file.  I'd suggest shutting the JBoss instance down.  Delete the tmp and data folders (they'll be recreated on startup).  Go to the deployments folder, delete your ear called "myear.ear".  Try starting things up again but watch to make sure in the log file it's not trying to deploy an EAR called "myear.ear", if it is, likely you have another EAR file with a different name but part of the configuration says it's called "myear.ear"

Comment: I deleted my ear from the deployments folder and tmp and data folders. I Tryed starting things up again and in the log file it's not trying to deploy an EAR called "myear.ear". But if I add the ear when the server is started it looks fine. If I start JBOSS with an ear in the deployments folder it falls.

Comment: JBoss 6 and 7 are picky about deployments, they like to have those .dodeploy, etc. files in there and get very confused IIRC when they think there should or should not be an app in the deployments folder based on those files and at least JBoss EAP 7 can get really ornery as it also adds an entry to the standalone.xml.  IMHO, I'd stick to the normal deployment methods of either using the JBoss console, the CLI scripts, or deploying from your development environment - e.g. dont just drop an EAR or WAR file in there and then start it up like we used to do in JBoss 5.

Comment: If any of this helped you out, let me know and I'll try and provide it as an answer that you might be so kind as to accept - if you still have questions, let me know and I'll try and help out!

Comment: I solved setting Auto-deploy Zipped to false and now it deploys correctly the ear. But after one second it undeploys the ear, saying: JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null. JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myear.ear. JBAS018558: Undeployed "myear.ear

Comment: So did that really fix it or do you have a new problem it looks like?

Comment: I think is another problem

Comment: Do you have deployments that are dependent on each other?  I see a red hat solution that mentions that null error but it relates to deployment dependencies and an app being deployed or redeployed but the dependent app is not being deployed or redeployed.  Its also strange that setting the deployment to unzipped works as long as you deploy via the means we discussed.  Also, update your question with what you did then add the stack trace from the log from when you deploy it and it gets undeployed, might help to see it all.

Comment: I think it tryed to deploy too much time. Icreated the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667563/jboss-undeploy-for-deploying-null

Comment: Okay, yeah JBoss can run out of memory, but you'd see that error.  Dont forget to select your answer as correct, you haven't done it yet ;-)  It's the greyed out check box

Answer (score 0):

I solved setting Auto-deploy Zipped to false.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out Ciro, I saw that error first but it only showed as a warning so I thought it might be something different!  Good catch.