# Jboss undeploy for deploying null

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

My jboss server starts without errors and deploys my ear but after some seconds it undeploys it:

> 16:03:34,762 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment scan of [U:\JBOSS_CFG\deployments] found update action
>
> 16:28:46,919 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "myear.ear" (runtime-name : "my-ear.ear")

```
[{
"operation" => "composite",
"address" => [],
"steps" => [
    {
        "operation" => "undeploy",
        "address" => [("deployment" => "my-ear.ear")]
    },
    {
        "operation" => "remove",
        "address" => [("deployment" => "my-ear.ear")]
    }
]
}]
```

> 16:28:51,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: my-ejb.jar) in 25ms
>
> 16:28:51,093 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment my-ear.ear (runtime-name: my-ear.ear) in 82ms
>
> 16:28:51,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018558: Undeployed "my-ear.ear" (runtime-name: "my-ear.ear")

Comment: Ciro, it could be a copy paste error from your logs, but at 16:03:34,762 theres a deployment scan but it doesnt deploy the EAR till 6:28:46,919.  Is that 100% correct.  Are you sure theres no errors being displayed as to why it's being undeployed?  When you restart the server, does it also deploy and then become undeployed?  What about if you stop the server, clean the tmp and data folders, then start the server? What files are listed in the deployment directory, e.g. the "." files regarding deployments.

Comment: I resolved disabling DeploymentScanner

Comment: Thats strange - I dont think you want to do that or should need to do that - but I guess it doesnt matter if you're not deploying code all the time - only bad thing I could see is that you'd have to restart your app server everytime you deploy something new, which if you have multiple apps in production - might be bad.  Glad you got it working